# Функция возвращает ответ поздно

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

Есть функция которая берёт данные с БД, но она возвращает их позже чем нужно. Как сделать чтоб согласовалось с моим решением, допустим мне надо чтоб эта функция полностью выполнилась и дальше перешла на другую?
Что для этого надо?

Comment: Попробуйте сформулировать заново, по пунктам. У вас в вопросе какой-то поток сознания.

Comment: Вы жалуетесь на долгий ответ – это абсурд. Функция выдаёт ответ, тогда, когда она его получила – раньше не выйдет. Тем более если база данных в интернете, то и не удивительно, что она возвращает ответ не так уж и быстро.

Comment: Можно последовательность дейтсвий создать ?чтоб действие 2 невыполнялось пока не выполнится действие 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

просто вызывай функцию внутри функции

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    request()
}

func request(){
...твой запрос 
 otherFunc()
}


func otherFunc(){
твой код...
}
```